# Is it possible to add line breaks before an image in Google Doc?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs-api

Currently retrieving images like this:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  
var styles = {};
styles[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
  
var imgs = body.getImages();
imgs[0].getParent().setAttributes(styles);
```

Is there some attribute I can add to place line breaks before image? Or maybe get the index of image and add line breaks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `Is there some attribute I can add to place line breaks before image?`, unfortunately, I couldn't find the attribute for directly achieving your goal. So in this case, I would like to propose `maybe get the index of image and add line breaks.`. When this is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var image = body.getImages()[0];
var index = body.getChildIndex(image.getParent());
body.insertParagraph(index, "\n")
```

- When you run the script, a line break is inserted before the 1st image in the body of Google Document.

#### Note:

- For example, when the line break is added after the inline image, you can use the script of `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getImages()[0].getParent().asParagraph().appendText("\n")`.

#### References:

- [getChildIndex(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getChildIndex(Element))
- [insertParagraph(childIndex, text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-text)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this and its appending a line break after the image, not before.

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In my environment, when an image is put as the inline image and the script is run, the line break is inserted before the image. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Google Document for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Can you do this?

Comment: I actually got it to run with your first bit of code. Thanks!

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.